# Winform inside a windows service in C# - Possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I am writing a windows service to process emails on a daily basis. This service includes a App.Config file, which has several  parameters for the service to work accordingly.

Every time, the admin user has to go and change / add / delete the  pair inside the  section using a text editor.

I am planning to include a windows form to load all the  pair from the  section and thinking of doing any modification through the form.

All I would like to know is whether it's possible to have a winform inside a windows service and open it when ever the configuration needs to be changed? I know we can have a seperated windows application and load the App.Config file of the windows service. I just want to avoid having a seperate app for this.

If you have done something very similar to this, please share your thoughts!

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: you can call a winforms from a windows service I did one yesterday as a matter of fact.. created a C# Service and called a Delphi Win forms executable try looking at `System.Diagnostics` class and the `Process` Class.. there are lots of examples on how to do this on stackoverflow as well as google

Comment: @DJ you used `Process.Start()` to start an external .exe. OP does not want another .exe. I think it is possible to create one .exe that acts both as a service (ServiceMain) and regular executable (Main), where the latter just shows a screen that lets you update the configuration.

Comment: I cant imagine the work flow...service is running and admin decides to change config..what do you thing he must do?

Comment: I would suggest re-thinking your design approach after reading the question again I must agree that this could be a serious security issue but who am I to make that call

Comment: A service cannot have a GUI. However, a service can start a non-service process that has a GUI. Or you can start a program that communicates with the service (using pipes, for example).

Comment: From [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6db8bc5d-4017-491d-8f99-5f47786e619f/how-to-convert-my-c-winform-program-to-service-program-) A service can have no UI component. I'm afraid that there is no way to make a service containg a Winform component. Another app winform partner would be a good solution to edit the app.config file.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a security issue if nothing else.

A Windows service runs in a different context and account and cannot interact with the desktop unless specifically allowed when installing the service. This is not enough of course so you'd also have to have the service running under the same account that is running the desktop - this in itself is really bad design and not something I would recommend.

You could also have the service executable decide what to do during launch, a common pattern is to have it spawn as a console application when debugging to simplify development. But then you'd have to stop the service and launch the service executable manually interactively to get the UI behaviour.

In any way, a separate configuration tool is the way to go.